# Geometry areas problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $BCDK$ be a convex quadrilateral such that $BC$ = $BK$ and $DC$ = $DK$.

$A$ and $E$ are points such that $ABCDE$ is a convex pentagon and $AB$ = $BC$ and $DE$ = $DC$ and $K$ lies in the interior of the pentagon.

Angle $ABC$ = 120 and angle $CDE$ = 60 and $BD$ = 2 , then determine area of the pentagon $ABCDE$.

Comment: Don't just copy the question as it is, throw in some of your work/thoughts too.

Comment: As it stands, the position of K, even given the position of all other points, is not uniquely determined, and has no bearing on the area. Are you sure you copied the question correctly?

Comment: This question is from RMO 2008

Comment: If $BC$ = $DK$ and $DC$ = $DK$ and $AB$ = $BC$ and $DE$ = $DC$ then they are all equal.  It seems a strange way to say this

Comment: I found RMO 2008 at http://rmonorthzone.com/rmo%20pdf/RMO2008.pdf but it doesn't have anything like this question.

Comment: This from RMO West Bengal region.

Comment: Anyone who doubt this can check in the back of "An Excursion in Mathematics" by S.A. Katre and Co. Its from Problem No.6 in RMO 2008.

Comment: It's listed here: http://mprakashacademy.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/RMO2001_13_.pdf  But there is a typo in your question: in the first line it is $BC=BK$.

Comment: You can upload an image to [imgur](http://www.imgur.com). Then, you can insert your image in your post such that your question get improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $BCDK$ is a parallelogram. Because $ABCDE$ is convex, the area of $ABCDE$, shown by $S(ABCD)$, is equal to
\begin{equation}
S(ABCD) = S(ABC) + S(CDE) + S(ACE)
\end{equation}
Let's assume $CD = a$ and $BC = b$. Then, $S(ABC) = \frac{b^2\sin120}{2}$ as $AB = BC = b$ and $\hat{ABC}=120$. Similarly, we have $S(CDE) = \frac{a^2\sin60}{2}$. We use the same trick to find area of $ACE$. We get $S(ACE) = \frac{AC.CE\sin(\hat{ACE}-(30+60))}{2}$, in which 30 and 60 are angles $\hat{BCA}$ and $\hat{ECD}$ respectively (they can be found considering the fact that triangles $ABC$ and $CED$ are isosceles). Because $ABC$ and $CED$ are isosceles, we can easily show that $AC = 2b\sin60$ and $CE = a$ (in fact CED is equilateral). So, put it together we get:
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
S(ABCD) &= S(ABC) + S(CDE) + S(ACE)\\
&+ \frac{b^2\sin120 + a^2\sin60 +  2ab\sin60\sin(\hat{ACE}-90)}{2} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Considering the fact that $\sin120 = \sin 60$ and $sin(\hat{ACE}-90) =-\cos(\hat{ACE})$, we get
\begin{equation}
S(ABCD) =  \frac{b^2 + a^2 -  2ab\cos(\hat{ACE})}{2}\sin60 
\end{equation}
Using the law of cosines, numerator is $BD^2$ which is 4. Thus, $S(ABCD) = 2\sin(60) = \sqrt3$.

Comment: $BCDK$ is NOT a parallelogram, in general.

Comment: The question is modified apparently, and my solution may not be true for the new version.